# Create symbolic links for multiple books collected from command `find`

Tags: bash, ln

I'd like to create links of books.

Firstly, I collect all the JS books

```
    find ~ -type f -iregex -Eo '.*javascript.*\.pdf' > js_books.md 2>/dev/null
```

It returns 35 books

```
    ../Coding/Books/HTML_Collections/Freeman E.T., Robson E. - Head First HTML5. Programming Building Web Apps with JavaScript - 2011.pdf
    ../Coding/Books/HTML_Collections/Learning Web Design - A Beginner's Guide to HTML, CSS, JavaScript, and Web Graphics - Jennifer Niederst Robbins - 4th Edition - August 2012.pdf
    ..
```

Additionally to copy them to directory js_books

```
    mkdir js_books
    find ~ -type f -iregex -Eo '.*javascript.*\.pdf' print0 -exec cp '{}' js_books
```

It works, however, multiple copies consume lots of disk space.
So I delete the books and try to make symbolic link within.

```
    find ~ -type f -iregex  '.*javascript.*\.pdf' -print0 -exec ln -s '{}' js_books/'{}' \;
```

It returns nothing in dir js_books.

How to work out such a problem?

Comment: Why the `-print0`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry again. I don't have access to BSD `ln` at the moment, but I would assume that '{}' contains the full path, and doing `'{}' js_books/'{}'` should get you something like `/home/.../file js_books//home/.../file`, which is of course nonsense.

In my version of `ln`, I don't even need to specify the `-t` option, i.e., the following command works:

```
find ~ -type f -name "*.pdf" -exec ln -s {} js_books \;
```

If this doesn't work for you, try using `basename` to get the file name without the path:

```
find ~ -type f -name "*.pdf" -exec sh -c 'ln -s "{}" "temp/$(basename "{}")"' \;
```

---

<del>Sorry. Previous answer didn't work so well.
Instead, try using full paths for both source and destination.</del>

---

<del>For reference, the previous answer was:</del>

<del>Use `ln`'s `-t` option:</del>

<del>`-t, --target-directory=DIRECTORY`</del>
<del>`specify the DIRECTORY in which to create the links`</del>

<del>So your command becomes `find ~ -type f -iregex  '.*javascript.*\.pdf' -print0 -exec ln -s -t js_books/ '{}'  \;`</del>

Comment: ty, there's no option `-t' in BSD version, I'm finding an alternative of '-t'

Comment: Sorry, I meant that the `-t` option probably won't help you. Instead, use the full paths for both the target and the link name.

Comment: That is, the `-t` option doesn't work if the link target doesn't have the full path. The command I'd recommend is `ln -s /full/path/to/target/file /full/path/to/link`

Comment: Wow, I kept editing my post and putting something slightly wrong, but I -think- it should be good now. And maybe I'd better go to sleep